# Trouble casting from int to struct

Tags: c++, casting, struct

SO I have the following structure definition

```
struct  sCount { U32 _; };
typedef sCount tCount;
```

but when I try to do the following code:

```
tCount Count = (U32)atoi(arg[10].c_str());
```

I get a Error: No suitable constructor exists to convert from U32 to tCount. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Add a suitable constructor, perhaps? Or else write `sCount Count; Count._ = atoi...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code `tCount` and `U32` are different and unrelated types.  There is no implicit, or explicit, conversion between them.  Instead the `tCount` type contains an instance of `U32`.  You need to assign the `U32` value to that field`

```
tCount Count;
Count._ = (U32)atoi(arg[10].c_str());
```

Or better, define a constructor which takes the value as an argument.  This will also enable the implicit version case

```
struct sCount {
  sConut(U32 value) : _(value) { } 
  U32 _;
}
```

Note: Given that the member `sCount::_` is public, it would be better if it had a more informative name than `_`

Answer (score 3):

I particularly don't like how you are doing things, but aggregate initialization will do what you want:

```
tCount Count = { (U32)atoi(arg[10].c_str()) };
```

Alternatively you could provide a constructor that takes the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error says, you need to create a constructor.
Just have a constructor that takes a single int parameter, and you can 'cast' from int to the class/struct type.